# Making hash value a variable

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write Ruby code to make the following Rspec code pass:

```
describe ThanksgivingDinner do

 before do
  @t_dinner = ThanksgivingDinner.new(:vegan)

 context "#menu" do

  it "should have a diet specified" do
   @t_dinner.menu[:diet].should eq :vegan
  end
```

The code I am trying to pass is as follows:

```
class ThanksgivingDinner < Dinner

 def initialize(diet)
  @diet = diet
 end

 def menu
  { diet: @diet }
 end
end
```

I keep getting told that instead of equalling vegan, a nil value is returned. How can I fix this to return the value from @diet in the initialize method?

Edit: here is the CL error:

```
3) ThanksgivingDinner#menu should have a diet specified
 Failure/Error: @t_dinner.menu[:diet].should eq :vegan

   expected: :vegan
        got: nil
```

Comment: 1 issue I am able to see is `diet = { diet: "@diet" }` should be `diet = { diet: @diet }`

Comment: Show the code where the object `@t_dinner` is created ?

Comment: You should show your whole spec and the actual error you're getting. You haven't shown how `@t_dinner` is initialized.

Comment: The whole spec is very long so I just added where @t_dinner is initialized.

Comment: Deleting the quotations worked! Thanks!

Comment: Are you still getting an error? The previous code should have given you `expected: "@menu"`, not `expected: nil`.

Comment: I am not getting an error... but thanks for checking!